# Proving d=gcd(a,b)

Tags: number-theory

Given $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ both non-zero, suppose that $d$ is a positive integer which is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and is also a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Then show that $d=gcd(a,b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D$ be the real $GCD(a,b)$. If there exist $m,n\in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$ma + nb  = d$$
Then the left hand side is divisible by $D$, so the right hand side should also be. Hence, if $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $d=D$.

---

As suggested by @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I should also have mentioned that $d$, which is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, divides the greatest common divisor, $D$. Hence $d \mid D$ and $D\mid d$.

Comment: Or, the linear combination proves that $D$ divides $d$, the other hypotheseis proves that $d$ divides $D$, so $d=D$. I know it's equivalent to what you wrote, but I find it interesting to show how the antisymmetric property of divisibility pops up in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By the hypothesis there's $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ such that
$$au+bv=d$$
Now if $s\in\Bbb Z$ such that $s$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then we see that $s$ divides $d$ hence $d$ is the greatest positive number that divides $a$ and $b$. Conclude.

Comment: You need the other hypothesis, otherwise, using only the linear combination, $d$ could be any multiple of the GCD, and possibly not a divisor of either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: In my phrase '$d$ is the greatest positive number that divides $a$ and $b$' you find what you talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ax+ by= d$, where $d$ is a positive common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Also,let $g=\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ then $g|a$ and $g|b$ and thus divides $ax + by=d$. If $d$ is not gcd it would lead to a contradiction since $d<g$.